# Spyder IDE - E275 missing whitespace after keyword (pycodestyles e275) - break, continue

Tags: python, spyder, pycodestyle

While using Spyder, I'm getting pscodestyles errors for missing whitespace after keyword.  This is happening any time I use `continue`, `break`, `return`, etc. If I do add a white space after this, then I get `W291 trailing whitespace`.  What is the proper way to fix this? I would like to avoid just disabling E275.

by popular demand, here is the example code:

```
for i in range(4):
  if i == 1:
    continue
  if i == 2:
    break
```

Python Version: 3.9.13,
Spyder Version: 5.4.0,
I haven't tried other versions.

Comment: Remove the white space it is redundant

Comment: I'm not following.  If I remove the whitespace from W291, I get E275.

Comment: Please post your code to help us help you.

Comment: Why is there no colon after `2`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 typo.

Comment: If the problem persists, you might have this issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/19565

Comment: @mkrieger1 good find!! It looks like this fix is going to be upgrading to Spyder v5.4.1+ https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/milestone/124.  No release date yet.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We're planning to release 5.4.1 before the end of the year (not exact date yet, sorry).